# Gradle NamedDomainObject is never configured

Tags: gradle, kotlin, plugins

I have a simple kotlin gradle plugin that creates a `container` and performs some action for every element in it, e.g. `container.all { doSomething() }`. However, it doesn’t seem that the `NamedDomainObjectCollection` is ever configured, properly. When `all` is called, every element has the initial default values.

Create container and add it.

```
// create publish container
val publishContainer: NamedDomainObjectCollection<PublishSpec> = project.container(PublishSpec::class.java)
project.extensions.add(CONTAINER_NAME, publishContainer)

// for every element in the publishing container
publishContainer.all {
    addPublicationRepository(this, myProject)
    addPublication(this, myProject)
}
```

`PublishSpec` is a fairly simple class with 4 mutable properties, including the required `name` property.

```
public class PublishSpec {

    var name: String
    var artifact: String = ""
    var taskName: String = ""
    var type: String = "default"

    constructor(name: String) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

However, the following simply evaluates `all` with `core` as a `default` type.

```
plugins {
    id "my-publish"
}

myPublish {
    "core" {
        artifact = "foo.zip"
        type = "archive"
        taskName = "fooTask"
    }
}
```

Does this not work anymore?

https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/02/gradle-goodness-create-objects-with-dsl.html

Comment: I'd suggest following the official guides from Gradle which are more up to date. https://guides.gradle.org/implementing-gradle-plugins/#declaring_a_dsl_configuration_container and https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_gradle_types.html#collection_types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that I was misunderstanding the usage of the container's `all` api. It turns out that `all` is intended to execute code whenever an element is added, but that does not infer that the object has been *configured*. So, I was seeing the intended behavior within the `all` closure, as the delegate `PublishSpec` instance had only been *initialized* with the *default* value.

In order to get *my* intended behavior, you have to iterate over the container in an `afterEvaluate` rather than relying on `all`

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishContainer.forEach {
        addPublicationRepository(this, myProject)
        addPublication(this, myProject)
    }
}
```

Note that in the blog post that I referenced, `all` is used in a different context than I had originally tried. The task execution happens after the project has been evaluated.